# Why it doesn't work on NPM but does work on Yarn?

Tags: javascript, npm, cucumber, babeljs, yarnpkg

I setting up my test framework with TypeScript, Babel and Cucumber. I want to make it without yarn but it doesn't work on NPM. On NPM tests run but don't see scenrios, on Yarn everything is fine.

Yarn setup (works):

```
"scripts": {
   "transpile": "rimraf /dist && babel --extensions .ts --out-dir /dist /src",
   "cucumber-compile": "npm run transpile && cucumber-js",
   "cucumber": "yarn cucumber-compile"
 },
```

Output after I run:

```
yarn run cucumber --profile api
```

[OUTPUT here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OBHR.png)

NPM setup (doesn't work):

```
  "scripts": {
     "transpile": "rimraf /dist && babel --extensions .ts --out-dir /dist /src",
     "cucumber-compile": "npm run transpile && cucumber-js",
     "cucumber": "npm run cucumber-compile"
   },
```

Output after I run:

```
npm run cucumber --profile api
```

[OUTPUT here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcGxo.png)

My index.ts:

[index.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qk4Sh.png)

My .babelrc

[.babelrc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URtV9.png)

Comment: Hey, can you please try `"cucumber": "npm run cucumber-compile"` in your npm scripts?

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm doing, I make mistake in this description. But this is not working :(

Comment: Did you try cleaning NPM cache?